# Opening window in jQuery ajax call triggers popup warning message in iPad safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, ipad, safari, popup

I have the following javascript code to make an ajax call and then open a pop up. It works flawless on desktops with any browsers, but I get the warning message "This site is attempting to open a pop up window" on iPad Safari, even when Safari's pop-up blocker settings are set to allow all pop-up.  After some investigation it appears to be an issue with window.open in the callback of the ajax call.. Is there a way around this? Thanks.

```
function openPopup(_url) {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false}); 
    jQuery.getJSON(  
        _url,  
        function(json) {  
            window.open(json.myUrl);
        }  
    );  
}
```